# ngDoCheck slows and make my application to infinite execution when I use it multiple times

Tags: angular

I am using ngDoCheck to get my session storage value immediately, but when I use it in different component second time its making my application very slow and unusable. Is there any solution to control it. Here is just an example of my code.

### header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }  from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router){} 

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  sessionstore(){
  let lang = "fr" 
  sessionStorage.setItem('lang', lang); 
  }

}
```

### header.component.html

```
<button (click)="sessionstore()"></button>
```

### product.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('lang'));
  }
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('lang'));
  }

}
```

### product.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

Comment: ngDoCheck is called too many times indeed. A better solution is probably using a Subject in a service that when you store the session (`sessionstore()`) you emit an event and the interested components `subscribe` to that event

Comment: You can also customise the ChangeDetection to OnPush() it will trigger th doCheck only if the data realy change, i mean not the content but the variabale reference.
see: https://angular.io/api/core/Component#changedetection

Comment: I already used this ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush , still problem exist

Comment: Hey, I would like to help you if you can provide more information why you want to listen to getSession in ngDoCheck. I will be availabel after offing working this afternoon.

Comment: My requirement is simple, on click of button in header component , immediately I want to get the get session value in product component without refreshing product component. Any way header is common for all component, when we route to product we can easily click that button which in header and immediately want to get the getsession result , if I use ngoninit I need to refresh product page

Comment: Then my posted solution would be the one you need. Using `getSession$(key)`

Comment: I used the code of your stackblitz only ,I am getting error in service file in my code 'keySubject is undefined' in setSession function ('object is possibly undefined' like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more like an architect quesiton, I would like to learn more about your project requirement.
Usually you dont want to touch `ngDoCheck` since it's called by every detection changes, see [How Change Detection Work](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/). In your case, I dont see why you want to get session every detection changes, common practice would be 1) Listen to the session change 2)trigger get session based on events.
See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/questions68018796ngdocheck-slows-and-make-my-application-to-inf?file=src/app/services/session.service.ts)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionService {
  private _subjectMap = new Map<string, Subject<string>>();

  // Set session in your app-header component
  setSession(key: string, value: string) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    const keySubject = this._subjectMap.get(key);
    keySubject.next(value);
  }

  // Get session based on your event or any condition
  getSession(key: string) {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  }

  // Listen to session changes.
  getSession$(key: string) {
    const keySubject = this._subjectMap.get(key);
    if (keySubject) {
      return keySubject.asObservable();
    } else {
      // Create a subject
      const newSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();
      this._subjectMap.set(key, newSubject);
      return newSubject.asObservable();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error in service file in my code 'keySubject is undefined' in setSession function ('object is possibly undefined' like this)

Comment: Reasons I can think of 1) check whether it is your typescript or linting version throw error (console.log) to check whether `keySubject` defined. Use ` keySubject.?next(value);` 2) If `keySubject` is not defined in the `setSession`, make sure to check your logic flow, you should listen to `getSession$(key)` before setSession(key).

Comment: I tried all possible solution, I created a service of same name and pasted the code, even though getting same error

Comment: I fixed that issue,replacing const keySubject = this.keySubject (declaring variable)